Is it possible to move circular pieces outward to create equal space between them?
I created these basic circular pieces and now I want to basically move them all equally outward so I get the same amount of space in between each piece. In the second picture I moved a couple of the pieces manually to show where I want to have space.
Is it possible to move these circular pieces outward to create space between them?
They are all separate objects.



Do you just want to move them outwards with an even distance or should the overall shape still form a circle? Because for the latter the answer below will not work, a similar problem as with Markus' answer on this question: How to make a subdivided torus with a square shaped cross-section?. My answer there is unfortunately specifically for the other question. The problem is, the segments are curved to form a circle of a certain radius. Moving them outwards would increase a circle's radius, but the segments are not matching that new radius.

@GordonBrinkmann I did notice that. The overall shape should still form a circle.

But then the question would be, how do you want it to expand? You have 6 circular arcs of 60° each, together they form a full circle of, for example, radius 1 m. Moving them outwards by 1 m from the center creates gaps between the pieces, but they will not match a circle of radius 2 m, because the arcs are each 60° of a smaller circle. Scaling them larger to a radius of 2 m will not work because the 60° arcs then still build a full circle without gaps. So the angles of the arcs have to be decreased, e.g. to 50° each, then you have gaps of 10° between them. Is that what you want?

I don't necessarily want to create a 10° angular gap between them. I want to have like straight rectangular shape between them. So I would think maybe the only option is, creating a full circle with the desired radius and then cutting pieces out of it?

Okay, the 10° were just an example of course, but that's basically how I understood it, in my opinion you had the following options to do this: expanding circle segments with 1. being the answer by @Lauloque but like 2. and 3. (no gaps) it seemed obvious to me that it's not what you want, so I thought it's either 4. or 5. (probably keeping the thickness though?), now I understand it's 5. Remaining question would only be, do you need it just cut once (then I'd do it manually) or dynamically changeable? Separate pieces or a single object?

The issue here is that each of your object have the exact same orientation, so they will always move in the same direction.
A way around that would be to start from one building block that is aligned with one axis, like here:

Then in Object Mode, press ⇧ ShiftD to duplicate, R to rotate the duplicate, and hold down ⎈ Ctrl to snap the rotation by increments. Move your cursor until the part is aligned edge-to-edge. Resulting in a duplicate object whose local X axis is aligned with it:

If you didn't click anything else, you can press Shift R to repeat the rotated duplication, or you can do it again manually, until you get this:

Finally, set your Transform Orientation to Local:

Select all the objects and move them on the X axis:

